# Как установить файлом на сервер базу данных sqlite3?

Tags: python, ubuntu, сервер, sqlite3

Есть сервер под операционной системы линукс, образ Ubuntu 22.04 самая последняя версия установлена.
Установлена sqlite3 3.37 версия, когда пытаюсь запустить файл он отказывается работать, в чем причина? Бот уже установлен, нужно только подключить базу данных.[image: Добавил скрин ошибки]

Запускаю файл users4.db он почему не хочет работать.

Comment: Нужно добавить в вопрос больше информации. Какая ошибка, как именно "запускаете файл"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sqlite база файловая, запускать её не нужно. Укажите путь к базе в своём сервер.